# Which LDAP server is used by default?

Tags: windows, active-directory, ldap

When doing LDAP requests in C# for example, I do not need to explicitly use an LDAP server address for `PrincipalContext` and `DirectoryEntry`. I can use one, but it will find users even without.

How does that work? Which one is used by default? Can I check which one the default is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active Directory "member" systems use DNS SRV records to discover domain controllers. The domain will usually have multiple DCs providing the same LDAP service, and your system's `Netlogon` service will choose one that's available (preferably in the same AD "site" as you).

The search base DN is derived directly from the DNS domain (i.e. there aren't any `o=Foo Inc.` directories in AD, unlike in non-AD LDAP systems). Authentication to the LDAP server is done automatically using your Kerberos credentials stored by Windows on login.

You can use `nltest` to look up all DCs or the system's chosen DC:

- `nslookup -q=SRV _ldap._tcp.<domain>`
- `nslookup -q=SRV _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.<domain>`
- `nslookup -q=SRV _ldap._tcp.<site-name>._sites.dc._msdcs.<domain>`
- `nltest /dsgetdc:<domain>`
- `nltest /dnsgetdc:<domain>`
- `nltest /dsgetsite`

You can also always watch the network packets to see what servers your program is communicating with.

Non-AD systems usually do not have a default LDAP server. (Though the `_ldap._tcp.<domain>` SRV records are often used outside of AD, not many LDAP clients will use them.)

Comment: Thank you, this gave me some useful info.